# Angular $compile on DOM changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have a Angular directive to build a table with [bootstrap table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table).

This table has a "formatter" for each column, to render the HTML data of a column, row by row.

The formatter must return a HTML, and in my case, my HTML is returning containing a ngClick.

But this ngClick isn't working, because angular hasn't compiled it.

How can I watch/monitor table DOM changes to force angular to processs/compile it directives after the changes?

I was trying this, but without success:

```
app.directive('myBootstrapTable', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            // watching for table DOM changes, to force angular to process it directives
            scope.$watch(function() { 
                return el.html(); 
            }, function(current, old) {
                $compile(el.contents())(scope); 
                console.log('bootstraptable: compile');
            });
        }

    };
}]);
```

Another possible problem is that I cannot compile more than 1 time an element. If I do this, for example, a ng-click will be executed twice.